# Insert an scanned pdf into database c#

Tags: c#, database, pdf, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to insert a pdf,  `PdfDocument doc`, into a database that contains a scanned document. When I try to add it, I got the next message error:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Implicit conversion is not allowed from type nvarchar to varbinary(max). Use the function CONVERT to execute this query.'

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and SQL Server 2012.

```
SqlCommand add = new SqlCommand("UPDATE table SET documento = @documento WHERE p = @contentP AND n = @contentN;", con);
add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@documento", Convert.ToString(doc));
add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contentP", contentP);
add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contentN", contentN);
con.Open();
add.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: @zaggler ```doc``` is defined as ```PdfDocument```, that is from the nuget ```PdfSharp```. Now i get this error: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument' to type 'System.IConvertible'.' When I put ```Convert.ToByte(doc)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Implicit conversion is not allowed from type nvarchar to varbinary(max). Use the function CONVERT to execute this query.'

Your issue is because you're trying to squeeze a `NVARCHAR` into a `VARBINARY(MAX)` column by doing `Convert.ToString(doc)`. You would have to get a `byte[]` and use that as your parameter value

To fix this error you would need to save the `PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument` to a `MemoryStream` and then get the `byte[]` from the stream, see below.

```
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(); 
 doc.Save(stream, false); 
 byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
```

Now you can use the `bytes` as your `documento` parameter value.